# php date - How to use "h" and "m" strings instead of colon?

Tags: php

I have the following at the moment:

```
<?= date('H:i', strtotime($eventOccurence->time)); ?>
```

And this will return something like:

> 12:22

I wish to replace the : with "h" and, after the i, add "m" so that is stays instead:

> 12h22m

I believe I can store this in a variable and *string replace* the first : with "h" and add at the end the "m".

Isn't there a more direct way to achieve this?
I see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) that there is a $format string that we can use, but I don't understand if we should use only the strings available, or if we can "create" our own formats...

Comment: Might be over-simplifying or missing something in your question, but surely you're just looking for `H\hi\m`?

Comment: Feel free to create your own formats. You'll need to backslash escape them, as both `h` and `m` are also available as formatting options.

Comment: try `date('H\hi\m', ...);` and read http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Comment: @Clive - I haven't found that information on the manual. I will check again. But that sure is what I was looking for. I may accept your answer if you provide one.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks a lot. Just found that is covered well under "Example #4 date() Formatting" page section, for this given function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you can escape characters with a backslash:

```
<?= date('H\hi\m', strtotime($eventOccurence->time)); ?>
```

Comment: Ok. So, H gives me the hour, then I backslash the lowercap h, the i gives me the minutes, and after that, I backslash the m. End up with the desired format. I think I got the syntax now. Thanks.

Comment: That's it - if you see a single backslash, the next letter will be interpolated verbatim, and `date` won't try to interpret it as part of the format

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('H').'h'.date('i').'m';
```

Comment: This will make two function calls whereas it can be done in just one by escaping the `h` and `m`.

Comment: Well, I did not know that it could be escaped. yet you down voted my answer for what? millisecond slower in performance? seriously LOL !

Comment: Why does everyone assume that the one who leaves a constructive comment is necessarily the downvoter? No wonder nobody bothers to comment at all.

Comment: Fwiw, I didn't think this answer deserved a downvote so I've upvoted it. I would appreciate you take back your revenge downvotes.